# How to convert a date string to date format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have date in varchar type in my table, I need to convert them into a date/ or timestamp format.

```
+------------------+------------------+
| publication_date | application_date |
-+------------------+------------------+
| 19900523         | 19821101         |
| 19900314         | 19830406         |
| 19901212         | 19830318         |
| 19940420         | 19830518         |
| 19900627         | 19830810         |
| 19900912         | 19831020         |
| 19900718         | 19831104         |
```

How would I convert these values into a date field format? i.e. 1990-07-18

NOTE: I want to replace these existing values with the new format.

Regards.

Comment: Use STR_TO_DATE, you can specify a format by which to parse. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1. Add a new column.
2. Insert to new column from the old column.
3. Drop your old column.
4. Rename your new column as your old column.

Or you can simply update it using the STR_TO_DATE function.